# Vertex-connectivity of connected, vertex-transitive graphs without $K_4$ is maximum possible

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

A graph is said to have optimal vertex connectivity if its vertex connectivity equals its minimum degree. According to [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9411221) arXiv preprint, it was shown by Mader in (Arch. Math., 1970) and (Math. Ann., 1971) that a connected vertex-transitive graph without $K_4$ has optimal vertex connectivity.  My question is: which of the two papers by Mader mentioned above proves this result, and what is the exact statement of this result?

This result implies that all connected vertex-transitive graphs with clique number 2 or 3 have optimal vertex connectivity. In particular, all connected Cayley graphs generated by transpositions (these graphs are bipartite) have optimal vertex connectivity.

Answer (score 7):

[This article](http://www.dim.uchile.cl/~mstein/extInfGT.pdf) by Maya Stein states the relevant results on these two papers by Mader (page 11):

> Which degree at each vertex do we need in order to ensure that our
>   graph has a $k$-(edge-) connected subgraph?
>
> It is known that in finite graphs a degree of $k$ is enough, and moreover
>   the subgraph will be the graph itself. In fact, every finite
>   vertex-transitive $k$-regular connected graph is $k$-edge-connected [27].
>   It is even k-connected, as long as it does not contain $K^4$ as a
>   subgraph [25].

- [25] W. Mader. Uber den Zusammenhang symmetrischer Graphen. Archiv der
  Math., 21:331-336, 1970.
- [27] W. Mader. Minimale n-fach zusammenhangende Graphen. Math. Ann.,
  191:21-28, 1971.

So the result you're looking for is on the 1970 paper.

Comment: I think "nite" should be "finite"? Perhaps the ligature did not survive the cut-n-paste process?

Comment: @GordonRoyle Thanks! Just a copy-paste gone wrong.

Comment: @Myshkin. Thanks.  I would appreciate if someone could confirm first-hand (from Mader's original paper) that this result is in Mader's paper.

Comment: @AshwinGanesan Indeed, the 1970 paper states this as a theorem: "Satz 4. Wenn ein zusammenhängender eckensymmetrischer Graph vom Grad $g$ keinen $V_4$ enthält, ist er $g$-fach zusammenhängend." — "Theorem 4. If a connected vertex transitive graph of regularity $g$ contains no $K_4$, then it is $g$-connected."